# Problemas com permissões ao criar pastas em servidor Linux utilizando mkdir

Tags: php, laravel, linux, permissões, mkdir

Tenho um sistema em PHP utilizando Laravel 4.2 onde utilizo o comando mkdir para criar uma pasta no diretório storage/pdf, o comando funciona no ambiente de Dev Windows, porém ao subir para o servidor da UOL as pastas não são criadas devidamente, estou utilizando o seguinte trecho de código:

```
$diretorio = storage_path() . "/pdf/" . \Auth::user()->ID;
$this->verificarEDeletarDiretorioExistente($diretorio);
mkdir($diretorio, 0777);

// Lógica para criar arquivo na pasta e enviar

$this->verificarEDeletarDiretorioExistente($diretorio);
```

Busquei na internet mas não encontrei nada que faça referencia a esse problema.
O servidor da UOL é um Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago).

Para melhor análise segue o método verificarEDeletarDiretorioExistente($diretorio):

```
private function verificarEDeletarDiretorioExistente($diretorio)
{
    if (is_dir($diretorio)) {
        $diretorioScan = array_diff(scandir($diretorio), array('.', '..'));

        foreach ($diretorioScan as $content) {
            unlink($diretorio . "/" . $content);
        }

        rmdir($diretorio);
    }
}
```

Comment: A primeira coisa a fazer é verificar os logs de erros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoje passei pelo mesmo problema. Em localhost o método criava o diretório e realizava a função sem problemas, porém no cliente não funcionava, dando um erro de path.

Resolvi setando o método com true o parâmetro recursive.
Para o seu problema:
Tente

```
mkdir($diretorio, 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o caminho completo de `storage_path()` não existe no servidor, você deve setar o parâmetro de recursividade como `TRUE`, para que seja criado o caminho completo recursivamente, veja na [documentação da função](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mkdir.php).

Se o caminho já existe e você apenas quer criar o diretório pdf e está tendo problemas com a mode de uso, do subdomínio pode ter que utilizar o comando [chmod](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.chmod.php) e definir as permissões dos subdomínios individualmente já que não há recursividade nesse comando.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor verificação é entrando no servidor e criando um script php simples para testar a criação através da função do mkdir...

```
<?php
mkdir('/storage/pdf/content', 0700, true);
chmod('/storage/pdf/content', 0777);
?>
```

Se ao final a pasta não estiver com permissão 777 então pode ser algo relacionado ao SELinux (se estiver habilitado), aí você terá de dar uma olhada no semanage no RHEL 6.